# Multipass - instances cannot resolve each others name but can resolve external names

Tags: 18.04, dns, macosx, multipass

I am running multipass 1.1.0 on MacOS 10.15.4. I have 3 Ubuntu 18.04 instances running.

Shelling into each, I am able to ping and resolve www.google.co.uk with no issue and am able to install packages with no problems.

I am able to ping the other multipass instances using their IP address but I cannot ping them using their given host name.

Am I missing something obvious? I am trying to setup a k3s cluster using these three instances. Without this local name resolution I cannot achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is [an open issue](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/853).

Editing /etc/hosts as a workaround may not work as expected. Worth checking [here](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004542834-The-etc-hosts-file-gets-overwritten-after-a-server-reboot-Your-system-has-configured-manage-etc-hosts-as-True) to work around the workaround

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1030733)

Comment: You can't edit /etc/hosts directly, the changes don't persist during restarts of the multipass instances.